# Umbraco on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to install Umbraco CMS on Windows 7 64-bit and I get the following exception:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'ImageManipulation, Version=1.0.2105.41209, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant
>   minimum permission required.

The application pool's trust mode is set to 'Full', all the user permissions are just as on other sites hosted on the same machine. I went through all relevant topics on Umbraco's forum, but all advices are about the trust level.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running FileMon or RegMon while loading up to see if you can find some related permissions issues with this?

Answer (score 1):

Bit specific for a usual SF question but [HERE](http://our.umbraco.org/search?q=ImageManipulation&content=wiki,forum,project,) is a link to a forum post chain about this exact problem on the Umbraco web site - hopefully you'll find an answer in there, lots of others seem to have the same problem.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Just use the link then search on 'ImageManipulation' - regards.